# Quasi-likelihood Estimation and Linear GEE

Tags: linear, normality-assumption, generalized-estimating-equations

I am trying to better understand some of the assumptions of the estimator I am using, which is linear GEE. It is my understand that linear GEE uses quasi-likelihood estimation and so it has weaker distributional assumptions for the dependent variable. As in, the dependent variable does not have to be normally distributed. Is this true for linear GEE or am I missing something? ...Also, because of these properties of linear GEE, does it make it more favorable than say random-effects GLS for estimating a dependent variable that is not exactly normally distributed?

Thank you in advance!